# Arithmetic equation for array elements not working

Tags: java, math, for-loop, methods, random

This is a program designed to estimate the value of pi using Buffons needle simulation. 
The problem I'm having here is that inside the method calcPi, the pi array's elements keep on showing up as 0 after the arithmetic equation inside the for loop. I've checked and the hitCounter and trial are both working.. Help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Darts
{
    public static int trials() //User Inputs number of trials
    {
        int input;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many darts/trials? ");
        input = in.nextInt();

        return input;
    }

    public static double [] randomX(int trial) // Randomly generates numbers for the x coordinate on the amounts of trials

    {
        double [] randNumArrayX = new double[trial];
        for(int i = 0; i < trial; i++)
        {
            randNumArrayX[i] = Math.random();
        }
        return randNumArrayX;
    }

    public static double [] randomY(int trial) // Randomly generates numbers forthe y coordinate on the amounts of trials
    {
        double [] randNumArrayY = new double[trial];
        for(int i = 0; i < trial; i++)
        {
            randNumArrayY[i] = Math.random();
        }
        return randNumArrayY;
    }

    public static int [] dartBoard(double [] randx, double [] randy) // determines whether the dark hit the board or not
    {
        int [] hitMiss = new int[randx.length];
        int [] trials = new int[randx.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < randx.length; i++)
        {
            if( Math.pow(randx[i] , 2) + Math.pow(randy[i] , 2) <= 1)
            {
                hitMiss[i] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                hitMiss[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        return hitMiss;
    }

    public static double [] calcPi(int [] h) // Calculates pi using randomly generated numbers
    {
        int hitCounter = 0;
        double [] pi = new double[h.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < h.length; i++)
        {
            if(h[i] == 1)
            {
                hitCounter++;
            }
            pi[i] = 4*(hitCounter/(i + 1));
        }
        return pi;
    }

    public static void print(double [] pi) // prints results
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%-7s%2d%-8s%-10.6f%n", "Trial [", i, "]: pi = ", pi[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("\t   .....");
        System.out.printf("%-17s%-10.6f%n", "Estimate of pi = ", pi[pi.length -1]);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) // main method
    {
        int t = trials();
        double [] x = new double[t];
        double [] y = new double[t];
        int [] h = new int[t];
        double [] p = new double[t];
        x = randomX(t);
        y = randomY(t);
        h = dartBoard( x , y );
        p = calcPi( h );
        print(p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is probably this line:

`pi[i] = 4*(hitCounter/(i + 1));`

You are doing an integer division and since `hitcounter` is always lower than `i` it will always return 0.

Try this

`pi[i] = 4*(hitCounter/(i + 1d));`

note the `1d` this will force a double division.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to integer division probably.

Try

`pi[i] = 4 * (hitCounter/(i + 1.0));`

The `1.0` literal in Java is of type double. Basically, from there 
on all other values in this expression will be promoted to double too.